# Find `$apply` or `$digest` invoker

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-digest

I'm looking for at way to track down the pesky error of

```
apply/digest is already in progress
```

I'm familier with not using the anti-pattern and have check my codebase for nested apply's/digest's.

The problem lies in third-party plugins in this case FormEditor and Flatpickr. I have nested FlatPickr (with angular add-on) into a formEditor cshtml file which gives me the pesky error.

Is there a way to track the location of all the invokation of apply and/or digest that are present in my project?

Or does anyone have a solution to formEditor with flatPickr and flatpickr angular add-on?

FormEditor: https://github.com/kjac/FormEditor FlatPickr: https://github.com/chmln/flatpickr FlatPickr add-on: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-flatpickr

> SOLUTION:
>   The problem was a $apply called by an eventListener which injected the apply into the running apply/digest. Used $timeout as suggested in the answer marked as correct.
>   The location was found by looking into the error log as suggested in comments

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code using a JS debugger such as the one provided in Chrome?  Can you share any code with us?

Comment: The caller (file and line) is specified in error call stack.

Comment: Unfortunately the codebase is to large to share, which is why the question is more principle based.
Chrome debug gives me an empty file association and all I get is the standard angular error, which provides me with no means of debug besides knowing another apply is in progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS automatically triggers a $digest cycle in many cases (after ng-click triggered for example) so the solution is not to find all the "apply / digest" in your code because it won't help you to prevent this error.

The right approach is to control 3rd parties calls to $apply method.

One approach can be wrapping $apply call with a safety check:

```
if(!$scope.$$phase) {
  // place 3rd party updates to scope here
  $scope.$apply();
}
```

The problem with this method is that sometimes you code won't be called.

The better approach will be to wrap it with $timeout 0:

```
$timeout(function(){
  // place 3rd party updates to scope here 
});
```

This way you merged more naturally into angular digest cycle.

Comment: That was my initial approach as well. Unfortunately the 3rd parties does not call  the $apply unless I make some kind of user input and therefore the problem is rather concealed. Also the suggestions you have is under the anti-pattern umbrella, which I would like to avoid, so that I can adress this issue appropriately